# What does the following excerpt from 'Modern C' by Jens Gustedt mean?

Tags: c, types

This is my first C programming book, prior to which I have taken some online courses on the language. It's been a smooth read until the following came up

> Binary representation and the abstract state machine.
>
> Unfortunately, the variety of computer platforms is not such that the C standard can completely impose the results of the operations on a given type. Things that are not completely specified as such
> by the standard are, for example, how the sign of a signed type is represented the (sign representation), and the precision to which a double floating-point operation is performed (floating-point representation). C only imposes properties on representations such that the results of operations can be deduced a priori from two different sources:
>
> - The values of the operands
> - Some characteristic values that describe the particular platform
>
> For example, the operations on the type size_t can be entirely determined when inspecting the value of SIZE_MAX in addition to the operands. We call the model to represent values of a given type on a given platform the binary representation of the type.
>
> Takeaway - A type’s binary representation determines the results of all operations.
>
> Generally, all information we need to determine that model is within reach of any C program: the C library headers provide the necessary information through named values (such as SIZE_MAX), operators, and function calls.
>
> Takeaway - A type’s binary representation is observable."

(Chapter 5, page 52-53)

Would someone explain it for me?

Comment: `size_t` is *unsigned*, and unsigned types are specified to have a "pure binary" representation (C11 draft standard n1570, *6.2.6 Representations of types* / *6.2.6.2 Integer types*). The only complication is that `size_t` may include padding bits, but you can determine the number of padding bits from `sizeof size_t`, `CHAR_BIT` and `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, i am still not following. I must state that this is just after author first introduces 'Data Types'. " Types. A type is an additional property that C associates with values. Up to
now, we have seen several such types, most prominently size_t, but also double and
bool.
Takeaway -All values have a type that is statically determined. Takeaway -Possible operations on a value are determined by its type.
Takeaway - A value’s type determines the results of all operations."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [ediŧ] your question if you have new information, down here in the comments it will not be seen. -- Please clarify what specifically you don't understand or where you stumble. You might want to present some examples, or your rudimentary understanding and tell us where the gaps are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the abstract state machine

*The abstract machine* is a term used by the formal C standard to describe the core about how a C program is supposed to behave, particularly in terms of code generation, order of execution and optimizations. It's a somewhat advanced topic so if you are a beginner, I'd advise to just ignore it for now. Otherwise, I wrote a brief explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101525/584518).

> Things that are not completely specified as such by the standard are, for example, how the sign of a signed type is represented the (sign representation), and the precision to which a double floating-point operation is performed (floating-point representation).

This refers to integers and floats having different sizes, different signedness formats, different [endianess](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640) and so on depending on system. Meaning that those types are usually not portable.

> C only imposes properties on representations such that the results of operations can be deduced a priori from two different sources:
>
> - The values of the operands
> - Some characteristic values that describe the particular platform

This is very broad, it doesn't mean much, basically just that in some cases the outcome of using an operator is well-defined by the language and in some cases it is not.

> For example, the operations on the type size_t can be entirely determined when inspecting the value of SIZE_MAX in addition to the operands. We call the model to represent values of a given type on a given platform the binary representation of the type.

> Generally, all information we need to determine that model is within reach of any C program: the C library headers provide the necessary information through named values (such as SIZE_MAX), operators, and function calls.

This probably means that for example we can check if an operator applied to operands of `size_t` will give the expected result or not:

```
size_t a, b = ...; // 
if(SIZE_MAX - a >= b)
{
  size_t c = a + b; // addition will not be larger than SIZE_MAX
}
else
{
  // a + b will not fit, handle error
}
```

But also that unsigned numbers have a well-defined wrap-around (unlike signed), so we can write code such as `if(a+b < a)` to check if an operation resulted in wrap-around. This behavior is well-defined and portable for unsigned numbers, but undefined behavior for signed numbers that may overflow.

In theory, any integer type in C (that isn't a character type) can contain exotic stuff such as padding bits. This is mainly there because C supports exotic signedness formats like one's complement and signed magnitude, but also because an integer type doesn't necessarily have to use all allocated bits. This is all highly theoretical language-lawyer stuff though and of no concern for beginners. In the real world, integers are almost certainly without padding bits and signed integers are almost certainly 2's complement.

Another related advanced topic: C has mechanisms to look at the raw binary representation of any variable, byte by byte. We can do so by casting the variable's address to a character pointer, then de-reference that pointer to get the raw binary representation. This isn't always possible in higher level languages - C is closer to the hardware than most languages.